# Display module on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks, controllers

I'm trying to write a module to display on my product page, but can't for the life of me get the initial blocks to display. Here's what I have so far:

**app/code/local/Eden/Finance/etc/config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Eden_Finance>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </Eden_Finance>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <finance>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Eden_Finance</module>
          <frontName>finance</frontName>
        </args>
      </finance>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
  <layout>
  <updates>
    <finance>
      <file>finance.xml</file>
    </finance>
  </updates>
  </layout>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <finance>
        <class>Eden_Finance_Helper</class>
      </finance>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <finance>
        <class>Eden_Finance_Block</class>
      </finance>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Eden/Finance/controllers/IndexController.php:**

```
<?php class Eden_Finance_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

**app/code/local/Eden/Finance/Blocks/Finance.php:**

```
<?php class Eden_Finance_Block_Finance extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function methodblock()
    {
        return 'test!';
     }


}
```

**app/design/frontend/eden/default/layout/finance.xml:**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
        </reference>
    </default>
    <finance_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="finance/finance" name="finance" as="finance" template="finance/init.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </finance_index_index>
    <finance_ajax_ajax>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <block type="finance/finance" name="finance_ajax" as="finance_ajax" template="finance/ajax.phtml" output="toHtml" />
    </finance_ajax_ajax>
</layout>
```

(init.phtml and ajax.phtml are set up inside `app/design/frontend/eden/default/template/finance/`)

In the `catalog.xml` file I've included the following:

```
<block type="finance/finance" output="toHtml" name="finance" template="finance/init.phtml"/>
```

and then finally included `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('finance');?>` inside my view.phtml page. This gives me the following errors in my exception.log file:

```
2018-06-20T12:56:24+00:00 ERR (3): 
Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type: Eden_Finance_Block_Finance in C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('Eden_Finance_Bl...', Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('finance/finance', 'finance')
#3 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('finance/finance', 'finance')
#4 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#8 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Product\View.php(73): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Helper\Product\View.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
#10 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(14570, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#11 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#12 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#13 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

It seems that my block type is invalid. Although when I change the catalog.xml entry to core/template instead, it works - but unfortunately, provides me no access to my Block and Helper functions. Is anybody able to guide me the right way to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you created your block class as well ?

Comment: Sorry, yes I have. I've updated my question :)

Comment: then you have to change block type to  `type="eden/finance"` in your XML file

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal then I get `Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type: Mage_Eden_Block_Finance in C:\wamp\www\eden\tmp\app\Mage.php:595`

Comment: Can you confirm your block file is at path `app/code/local/Eden/Finance/Blocks/Finance.php` as  there is an extra 's' in Block directory name (`Blocks` should be `Block`)

Comment: Your file path is wrong. Block `Finance.php` file should be inside `Block` folder not `Blocks`.

Comment: @Piyush bingo! Silly mistake! Many thanks both of you!

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/local/Eden/Finance/Block/Finance.php

```
<?php
class Eden_Finance_Block_Finance extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

> app/design/frontend/eden/default/layout/finance.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
        </reference>
    </default>
    <finance_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="finance/finance" name="finance" as="finance" template="finance/init.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </finance_index_index>
    <finance_ajax_ajax>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <block type="finance/finance" name="finance_ajax" as="finance_ajax" template="finance/ajax.phtml" output="toHtml" />
    </finance_ajax_ajax>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also used another way to call your file.
Put below code into `view.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('finance/finance')->setTemplate('finance/init.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: I have created a custom PHP file under app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/top_selling_items_list/top_selling.php, what is my block type in cms. mine getting error - {{block type="top_selling_items_list" template="top_selling_items_list/top_selling.php"}}  @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: @Gem Yes it give the error because you used the block which is not exist.

Comment: How to write the proper way? @ Dhiren Vasoya